# Getting exception 1003 when importing images via feeds module

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm importing images via the feeds module from a csv file. In the field for images, I've added the `public` url like so:

```
public://path/to/my/image.jpg
```

I've verified that the image exists and is available. When I try importing the feed, everything imports fine but I get the following two db errors for every image:

First error:

> exception 'Exception' with message 'Download of
> public://path/to/my/image.jpg failed
> with code -1003.' in
> /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds/plugins/FeedsParser.inc:424
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds/plugins/FeedsParser.inc(483):
>
> FeedsEnclosure->getContent()
>
> ## 1 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds/mappers/file.inc(127):
>
> FeedsEnclosure->getFile('public://images...')
>
> ## 2 [internal function]: file_feeds_set_target(Object(FeedsSource), Object(stdClass), 'field_y1_rankin...', Array, Array)
>
> ## 3 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds/plugins/FeedsProcessor.inc(800):
>
> call_user_func('file_feeds_set_...', Object(FeedsSource),
> Object(stdClass), 'field_y1_rankin...', Array, Array)
>
> ## 4 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds/plugins/FeedsProcessor.inc(746):
>
> FeedsProcessor->mapToTarget(Object(FeedsSource), 'field_y1_rankin...',
> Object(stdClass), 'public://images...', Array)
>
> ## 5 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds/plugins/FeedsProcessor.inc(296):
>
> FeedsProcessor->map(Object(FeedsSource), Object(FeedsParserResult),
> Object(stdClass))
>
> ## 6 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds/includes/FeedsSource.inc(399):
>
> FeedsProcessor->process(Object(FeedsSource),
> Object(FeedsParserResult))
>
> ## 7 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds/feeds.module(191):
>
> FeedsSource->import()
>
> ## 8 [internal function]: feeds_batch('import', 'y1_rankings_pro...', '109600', Array)
>
> ## 9 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/includes/batch.inc(284):
>
> call_user_func_array('feeds_batch', Array)
>
> ## 10 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/includes/batch.inc(161):
>
> _batch_process()
>
> ## 11 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/includes/batch.inc(80):
>
> _batch_do()
>
> ## 12 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/modules/system/system.admin.inc(2384):
>
> _batch_page()
>
> ## 13 [internal function]: system_batch_page()
>
> ## 14 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/includes/menu.inc(527):
>
> call_user_func_array('system_batch_pa...', Array)
>
> ## 15 /srv/bindings/c09f123e774147dcaf40119f13d240c3/code/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
>
> ## 16 {main}

Second error:

> Invalid enclosure public://path/to/my/image.jpg

The feed *used* to work, and I don't think I've changed anything to break the import. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the image wasn't found, because my `path/to/my/image.jpg` was incorrect on my spreadsheet, `path/my/to/image.jpg`.